# Output a Twig tag within another Twig tag

Tags: templating, layout

I have a Matrix with a block for a contact form. I have a field for the email recipients. But the output doesn't work.

How can I render/output the output a tag within another tag, like this?

```
<input type="hidden" name="toEmail" value="{{ '{{item.mailto}}'|hash }}">
```

Answer (score 3):

You are hashing the string `'{{item.mailto}}'`. There shouldn't be any need for the quotes or second set of curly braces.

Twig does not permit curly braces inside curly braces.

Try `{{ item.mailto|hash }}` instead.

Comment: {{ item.mailto|hash }} work's fine. Thx